# unable to run kivy programs

Tags: python, terminal, kivy

not able to run any kivy script

getting this error when running

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\akshd\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-01-12_9.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\akshd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\akshd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\akshd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage
```

the error is the same for any script of kivy

running python 3.9
(initially tried on 3.10.1 but, its supported only on 3.6-3.9 so, went with that...)

Comment: Try adding `%AppData%\Python\share\glew\bin;%AppData%\Python\share\sdl2\bin;` to your PATH

Comment: Running the following will do it and test the sdl2 window code for kivy as well `cmd /C "PATH=%AppData%\Python\share\glew\bin;%AppData%\Python\share\sdl2\bin;%PATH% && python3 -c ^"from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage^""`